# VBA Excel cellvalue is "not" NULL

Tags: vba, excel

I get cells value in a for loop like that:

```
cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
```

Then I check the value of the cell, if it's empty I need to skipp, like that:

```
    If (Not IsEmpty(cellValue)) 
       /doThings/
```

Even if the cellvalue is empty, the `IsEmpty(cellValue)` condition turn to befalse. I added a watch, to see what's inside these cells, but I got nothing:

[image: Empty cell]

In these cell I have a formula, which returns "" if some condition not true, thats why the cell is become empty.

Comment: Its value isn't `Null`, it is probably an empty string. `If cellValue <> ""`

Comment: `IsEmpty` only works with a `Variant`. How did you define `cellValue` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to check if a cell is empty or not is to use this

```
If Len(Trim(cellValue)) <> 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
If Not IsEmpty(CellValue) OR CellValue <> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(i, j)) then
```

should work !

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "" as well

```
cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
If (Not IsEmpty(cellValue)) Or cellValue <> "" Then
   'Do stuff
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
if cellValue.value = "" then
   'do stuff
end if
```